# How do I prevent deleted records from appearing in my AWS Amplify GraphQL results?

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify

By default the Amplify GraphQL APIs return deleted items.

Worse, as near as I can tell there is apparently no way to filter them: Neither `syncXYZTable` nor `listXYZTable` queries accept the `_deleted` field as a parameter. Fortunately the generated code in the DataStore SDK filters out these items, and (somewhat confusingly) the Amplify Studio does not display them (in the Contents tab); but this only highlights the inconsistency: For example as a developer I don't see deleted items anywhere, but as a data scientist or manager using the GraphQL API, I have (it seems) no way of avoiding them.

Am I missing something. Is there really no way to filter out deleted items using the Amplify GraphQL API?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when working on a project which had multi frontend one uses Datastore and other not, so I made lambda function to clean any deleted records from the tables, if you prefer this approach follow these steps:

**1-** Go to AWS console and create new lambda function ‘DeleteItemsForDatastore’

**2-** Go to function **configuration** under the execution role click on **Role name link** this will redirect you to the role page click on **add permissions** and select **attach policies** and search for `'AWSLmbdaInvocation-DynamoDB'` and add it, and again click **Add Permissions** select **Create inline policy** and search for `DynamoDB` and on **write** section select `'DeleteItem'` and add it.

**3-** Now update your lambda code

```
import { DynamoDBClient, DeleteItemCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb'

export const handler = async (event) => {
  
  const client = new DynamoDBClient({ region: 'us-east-1' })
  
 console.log(`EVENT: ${JSON.stringify(event)}`)
 
  for (const record of event.Records) {
      console.log('Data---> ', record.dynamodb)
      const tableName = record.eventSourceARN.split('/')[1] 
       const params = {
          TableName: tableName,
          Key: record.dynamodb.Keys,
        }
        
        const command = new DeleteItemCommand(params)
        const r = await client.send(command)
        console.log('response--> ', r)
  }
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify('Items Deleted Successfuly!'),
  };
  return response;
};
```

and deploy, this code will delete any records in the event but don’t worry we will add filter in next step.

**4-** Go to lambda **configuration** on **triggers** click **add trigger** and search for `DynamoDB` and select your table name form the list and change **Batch size** to 1, and down on **additional settings** click add on **filter criteria** and past this criteria

```
{ "dynamodb": { "NewImage": { "_ttl": { "N": [ { "exists": true } ] } } } }
```

now only when the record have _ttl (which only exist on deleted items) the function will invoke this will reduce invoking cost, now you can add triggers to all the tables that you want to clean deleted items from

Comment: I think this is now a feature on the latest Amplify, no? (Anyway, I've abandoned Amplify — short for "amplify the amount of time and frustration involved in simple things — and moved to Heroku.)

Answer (score -1):

I had to filter these _deleted records in the code. Did not find a way to filter out in GraphQL Response

Comment: Yes, filtering them in code after the response is the only way anyone has found. The question is whether they can be filtered _using the Amplify GraphQL API_.